# torch.pow() results in Nan

Tags: python, pytorch

In my CNN model there is a MLP which has 4 fully connected layers with last one having just one node. This output I call `alpha` and has 2 dimensions as in this sample output of `alpha` `[[0.1023]]`. I make sure that minimum values never goes below 0.1 using `alpha=torch.clamp(alpha,min=0.1,max=2)`

I need now to raise some other Pytorch tensor `x` with `alpha`. Both are in `torch.float` type. The Pytorch tensor `x` has 4 dimensions `(Batch, Channel, Height,Width)`.

So I have tried the following:-

- `x**alpha`
- `x**alpha[0][0]`
- `x.pow(alpha)`
- `x.pow(alpha[0][0])`

But just after the first iteration both `x` and `alpha` become `nan`. ***Why this happens***?

However, if I do the following:-

- `x.pow(alpha.item())`

The problem goes away. But I am ***not sure if backpropagation can happen through .item()***. And even backpropagation happens, why this is alright and aforementioned techniques result in Nan just after the first iteration. I use a very small learning rate of `1e-4` with Adam Optimiser. I am using Pytorch 1.3.1.

Comment: I do not know if this helps, but usning nn.Threshold instead of torch.clamp, does not cause any problem.

Comment: Hi Mohit, did you figure out a solution to this issue? I seeing that torch.pow() results in NaN, but I am not using torch.clamp anywhere.

Comment: No, I finally dropped using it. But I guess using small eps value inside pow should help.`(x+1e-5).pow(alpha)`